What is the second meaning of word adjoint in linear algebra?
Chapter 7 of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right writes

The word adjoint has another meaning
in linear algebra. In case you encounter the second meaning elsewhere,
be warned that the two meanings for
adjoint are unrelated to each other.

I understand that linear maps between inner-product spaces have adjoints, and so do matrices. These two kinds of adjoints are closed related in that if A is the matrix representation of a linear map T, then the adjoint (i.e., conjugate transpose) A* of A is the matrix representation of the adjoint T* of T. So, I do not think Axler considers these two kinds of adjoints have different meanings.
What might be this "second meaning of the word adjoint in linear algebra"?

Isn't the adjoint one of those intermediary matrices in one of the definitions of the determinant?

It's also used in linear algebra as the adjugate matrix... the matrix is also called the adjoint matrix.

Here is the Wikipedia page for the adjugate matrix, which is sometimes referred to as the "adjoint".

It might also be referring to "adjoint functors".

The second meaning of the word "adjoint" in linear algebra is the transpose of the cofactor matrix (see the link to the Wikipedia article in Ben Grossmann's comment above). This is not the same as the matrix of the adjoint of the linear map. It's better to use the alternative terminology "adjugate matrix" to avoid confusion between these two different meanings of the word "adjoint".

Never would I think to see Sheldon Axler on Math.SE.

Sheldon, it's fantastic to get a response directly from you.

It is perhaps a little bit of a stretch to say the two meanings are completely unrelated to each other. In the language of linear maps the processes in which those two "adjoints" arise are fairly similar.
For simplicity let us consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over some field $k$. To every $k$-linear map $f\colon V\to V$ corresponds a dual map $f^*\colon V^*\to V^*$ defined by $V^*\ni g\mapsto g\circ f$. In terms of matrices this is just the transpose matrix (if you choose appropriate bases). If one picks an isomorphism (or anti-linear isomorphism) $\flat\colon V\to V^*$ (usually by choosing an inner product if $k=\mathbb R,\mathbb C$), we get a $k$-linear map
$$
\flat^{-1}\circ f^*\circ \flat\colon V\to V,
$$
which is then called the adjoint of $f$ (w.r.t. the chosen inner product).
The other "adjoint" starts with a $k$-linear map $f\colon V\to V$ and its corresponding $k$-linear map $\Lambda^{n-1}f\colon \Lambda^{n-1}V\to \Lambda^{n-1}V$ where $n=\dim(V)$. One now again constructs a sort of "dual map" of this last map by
$$
(\Lambda^{n-1}f)^*\colon \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^{n-1}V,\Lambda^{n}V)\to \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^{n-1}V,\Lambda^{n}V), \ g\mapsto g\circ \Lambda^{n-1}f.
$$
Using the isomorphism
$$
\Phi\colon V\to \operatorname{Hom}(\Lambda^{n-1}V,\Lambda^{n}V), \ v\mapsto \Phi(v),
$$
where $\Phi(v)$ is defined via $\Phi(v)(w)=v\wedge w$, we get a $k$-linear map
$$
\operatorname{adj}(f):=\Phi^{-1}\circ (\Lambda^{n-1}f)^*\circ\Phi\colon V\to V,
$$
which by choosing appropriate bases corresponds to what is sometimes called the adjugate matrix.
